# My Git Hub Action "build and publish docker" stays Pending Indefinitely

Tags: github-actions

I have created an **Github Action Workflow** to build and publish (on REGISTRY: **ghcr.io**) one
docker image.
Note that this image is large : **6.06GB** (see with "docker images", builded locally with success).

**Could that explain the any worker never takes my Job ?**

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you post your actions.yaml ?

Comment: Hi, the original repo is private, I made a public one with the necessary information : action.yaml and Dockerfile https://github.com/dgerinmem/github_actions_docker_builder_issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is not clear ? From the Action workflow posted above with its Dockerfile, the worker never starts. I m asking what sould cause this "infinite pending state" ?